# Tab bar as a filter button on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can i create tab bar like this with xaml ? ,  with clicking on them , i wanna do filter on list of numbers with linq .

i am beginner on Xaml .

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
var qry = MyDB.TableName.Where(u => u.StartsWith == "F").ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @mohamed . actually i have no problem with c# . as i told you i am beginner in xaml ... and i just wanna know that how ca i create this bar with xaml ... sorry if my explanation was not good and made you confusing .

Comment: so, do you want xaml code for creating tab bar like that. Why not you prefer pivot controls.

Comment: Thanks for replying . if i use pivot control , how can i change the header item template ?  because i wanna create it like the picture above .

Answer (score 0):

That is a horizontal `ListBox` which has a `Tap` handler to refresh the grid below.

It is hard to write a complete answer because the code depends on your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I Created that bar by  Pivot Control :

```
                <phone:Pivot  Height="40" Background="#F9A11D" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" >
                <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="Alle"/>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="A-E"/>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="F-J"/>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="K-O"/>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="P-T"/>
                <phone:PivotItem Header="U-Z"/>
            </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Pivot is not an answer since that is completely different control.